# Nested Json as input in POST method

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I use Fiddler to call my method. Here are the parameters:

```
{"timestamp":"",
"json":
    {
        "something":[{"text":"bla","status":"1"},{"text":"sfdf","status":"1"}],
        "somethingElse":[{"description":"description""status":"1"}],
        "som1":[{"id":"1""status":"1"}]
    }
 }
```

The path to the method is correct. Here is the signature:

```
public void MyMethod(string timestamp, string json)
```

But it never gets called. How to modify my method so that it gets called? Should the parameter 'json' be not string?

I make the call via Fiddler. My method is in C#. The project is Wcf service.

I tried changing the type of json from string to object, and the method gets called, but json has no value.

Comment: I wonder what language you're using and what environment your setup is in? Please retag and add some more info.

Comment: @NickWeaver I make the call via Fiddler. My method is in C#.

Comment: WCF, Web Service, Web API, Open Rasta?

Comment: @Srcee, what binding are you using for this service?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov webHttpBinding

Comment: Does that second parameter (json) get deserialised to a string?? It looks like some sort of array of data. Also, it looks like there are potentially missing commas between values in the last two elements of the array.

Comment: When you change it from string to object it gets called but json doesnt have a value because you are using the type as object which is generic. Try using a specific type for the json parameter as the framework would be able to deserialize the value to that specific type of object then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was creating a new class which had these properties: List, List, List, and I changed the method:

```
public void MyMethod(string timestamp, theNewClass json) ;
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your interface,

```
 public interface IRestFulWCF
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "MyMethod")]
    [WebInvoke(
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate="/Example",
        Method="POST",
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)
    ]
    public void MyMethod(string timestamp, string json) ;
```

}

please post your interface detail end web.config here  if this is not helping you.